# Is there a module to translate blocks and pages with language modules?

Tags: 7, blocks, i18n-l10n

I am working on drupal 7, and I want to translate each Block/Pages/Node to multiple language.

Is there any module available that will provide facility language tabs to enter language specific content and save?

```
[<English>]  [Spanish]
|---------------------------------|
| Lorem Ipsum                     |
|                                 |
|---------------------------------|

<Save Content>
```

I have tried following modules:

- [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n).
- Locale (core module).

It only works on Plain/Text format to translate, I need module which allows me to support all Format to translate content in Block/Page/Node, etc.

Answer (score 5):

## Block languages submodule of i18n

Submodule `i18n_block`, included in the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module, could be what you're looking for ... or at least address part of your question.

Some more details about it:

> This module provides support for multilingual blocks.
>
> You can set up a language for a block or define it as translatable:
>
> - Blocks with a language will be displayed only in pages with that language.
> - Translatable blocks can be translated using the localization interface.

## Bean module

Consider looking at the [BEAN](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean) module also. It offers all sorts of enhancements as compared to the (old fashioned) blocks. And possibly you may want to combine it with modules such as [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) to achieve your goal.

The video tutorial [Drupal Bean module tutorial - using Bean Admin UI](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Eu1YNy-BNG8) provides a great introduction to really understand the power of the [BEAN](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean) module, and the kind of things you can do with it (by only using site building techniques, no custom coding involved). It also shows how the Bean module transforms Drupal blocks into fieldable entities.

## Managing translations

To actually "manage translations", there are a few typical modules like these (quotes from their project pages, with some bold markup added here):

- [Translation Management Tool](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt) (RC-version for D7).

> ... provides a tool set for translating content from different sources. The translation can be done by people or translation services of all kinds. It builds on and uses existing language tools and data structures in Drupal and can be used in automated workflow scenarios.
>
> This module does not make i18n or any other language module for Drupal obsolete. It does only facilitate the translation process.

This module seems already well ported to Drupal 8 also, so much that it is already recommended as a successor of the [Translation Overview](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_overview) module (which is about translations of  nodes), which also refers to the [Translation Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_table) module (which is about translations of taxonomy terms and menu items).

- [Translation Management](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_management)  (No version for D7, only for D6).

> ... provides complete workflow management for multilingual Drupal sites.
>
> Content managers can manage all translations from one central page. The module shows which contents need translation and notifies translators about what they need to do.
>
> ... The module introduces a new Translator role. This role allows translating between specific language pairs. Translators have individual job queues, showing documents that were sent to them for translation.
>
> ... Translators can translate everything without having to learn Drupal administration. **Node contents**, menus, taxonomy, CCK, **blocks** and strings are all translated from the same interface.

Note: even though there is no D7 version (yet), there are quite a few [D7 related issues](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/translation_management?status=All&version=7.x) (and there is a [GIT branch for D7](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/translation_management?h=7.x-1.x) also). And there is the [Drupal-Translation.com](http://drupal-translation.com/) website with tons of interesting documentation.

## Interface translations

The **translation of the interface** is about the translation of various text strings used throughout the site, like labels used on buttons such as submit, or on tabs such as view or edit. They are the same on all sites (no matter what actual content is contained in a site).

To manage these kinds of translations, there is the [Localization update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module.

## More translation modules

Translations in Drupal is fun, here are a few more to finish:

- [Language Icons](http://drupal.org/project/languageicons).
- [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable).
- [Title](http://drupal.org/project/title).
- [Entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity).

Comment: I am updating above given instruction to my drupal

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean with this comment here, can you retry/rephrase please?

Comment: I have used i18n module and setting up all things perfect. and Its working fine in my site.

e.g.
English Version URL
`http://www.drupal-experiment.local:90/home`
Spanish Version URL
http://www.drupal-experiment.local:90/es/home

Is there any other way to do without change URL, I mean passing language params as `es`

Comment: Because, Google Analytics has previous records without `es`

Comment: I still don't understand your last 2 comments, can you retry/rephrase them to better explain what exactly you mean? Also, could it be that this is a new/other questions (which you should post also as a separate question)?

Comment: @AshwinP : No more feedback on this? Did you get it to work somehow? If so: how?